# Duplicating image using jQuery clone and manipulating file type input field tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, cloning

I am using laravel
This is working for duplicating image while creating posts and saving them

```js
$(".imageblockbtn").click(function () {
    var langid = jQuery(this).attr("id");

    $(
      `#dynamic${langid}`
    ).append(`<div class="col-12 form-group qwer" id="imageblock">
                                                <label for="imageblock">Image Block</label>
                                                <input class="imageblock" type="file" accept="image/*" name="data[${langid}][imageblock${k}]"><span class="up"></span><span
                                                class="down"></span>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn remove-dyna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:18px;color:red">remove_circle</i></button>

                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                        <a class="dropbtn">Duplicate</a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-content image_dd" style="list-style-type:none">

                                                        <li id="1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">English</a> </li>
                                                        <li id="3"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Chineese</a></li>
                                                        <li id="9"><a href="javascript:void(0)">German</a></li>
                                                        <li id="10"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Italian</a></li>
                                                        <li id="4"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Korean</a></li>
                                                        <li id="5"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Japanese</a></li>
                                                        <li id="6"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Spanish</a></li>
                                                        <li id="11"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Russian</a></li>
                                                        <li id="7"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ukranian</a></li>
                                                        <li id="8"><a href="javascript:void(0)">French</a></li>

                                            </ul>
                                            </div>

                                            </div>`);
    ++k;

    $(".image_dd li").each(function (index, li) {
      var lid = $(li).attr("id");
      // console.log($(li).parents(".qwer"));
      $(li).unbind("click");
      $(li).on("click", function () {
        var file = $(li).parents(".qwer").find(".imageblock").files;
        var clone = $(li).parents(".qwer").clone(true);

        clone.children("input").files = file;
        clone.children("input").attr("name", `data[${lid}][imageblock${k}]`);
        clone.insertAfter(`#dynamic${lid}`);
        ++k;
        alert("Duplicated");
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But while editing the post i need to clone the image and save it into database..i am able to clone the image but without input field it cannot be accessed with requests method..is there a way to set the value of input type file with an image element from the dom which i cloned from another language??

Comment: You can not arbitrarily specify the value for a file input field, no. At most you can use `cloneNode` to clone a file input field in which the user has already made a selection.

Comment: yea i used it while creating posts but i dont know what to do while i am editing

Comment: Show the user the existing image via an `img` element, and offer them to upload a new one via a file upload field, if they want to.